# rvalue в параметр функции

Tags: c++

У меня имеется `unique_ptr`, который передаётся в функцию по значению.

```
void some_func(std::unique_ptr<some_class> ptr) {}
```

Почему когда я передаю `rvalue` (полученное из `std::move()`) оно корректно переносится в параметр? Где про это прочитать?

```
some_func(std::move(my_unique));
```

И почему, если я передаю туда же `rvalue` полученное через `std::make_unique` не происходит копирования? Это copy/move elision?

```
some_func(std::make_unique<some_class>());
```

Comment: Так в обоих же случаях передаете xvalue, почему тогда должна быть какая-то разница? И вообще unique_ptr не поддерживает копирование как таковое. По поводу семантики перемещения я бы посоветовал почитать книгу Майерса.

Comment: @Croessmah то, что в unique_ptr нет конструктора копирования - понятно. Вопрос именно из-за этого появился - т.к. я понял, что копирования не происходит (раз компилируется) - следовательно, непонятно почему. Где можно прочитать про то что происходит в момент передачи xvalue в параметр?

Comment: в обоих случаях вызывается перемещающий конструктор

Comment: @Croessmah хитро. Спасибо большое! Оформите в виде ответа, я Вам плюс поставлю

Answer (score 0):

В обоих случаях копирования не происходит, потому что в обоих случаях вызывается перемещающий (`move`) конструктор, создающий новый объект типа `unique_ptr`, передающий ему владение ресурсом и помещающий `nullptr` в умный указатель, передавший владение.

Таким образом, ресурс не копируется. Происходит лишь передача владения им.

Про семантику перемещения в общем можно почитать в книге ["Эффективный и современный C++: 42 рекомендации по использованию C++11 и C++14"](https://market.yandex.ru/product--meiers-skott-effektivnyi-i-sovremennyi-s-42-rekomendatsii-po-ispolzovaniiu-c-11-i-c-14/13104972?clid=703) Скотта Мейерса.

С конструкторами же класса `std::unique_ptr` можно ознакомиться на сайте [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr).